# Return function from background thread

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

My function execution is taking time

```
    func hasValidValues() -> Bool{
        let leftValue = Double(leftTextValue) ?? 0
        let rightValue = Double(rightTextValue) ?? 0
        switch self.stackViewType {
            let leftValid = self.hasValidValue(min: targetMin, max: targetMax, value: CGFloat(leftValue), unitConversation: true)
            let rightValid = self.hasValidValue(min: 0, max: plusMinusLimit, value: CGFloat(rightValue), unitConversation: true)
            return leftValid && rightValid
}
```

Now I need to execute this in background thread, and wanted to return so UI thread can access it and I can change UI in another controller.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: //If you want to do changes in UI use this
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

})

Comment: You have add completion handler closure as argument as background task is async. so after background thread completed switch to main thread using  DispatchQueue.main.async then call the completion handler

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Can you give me any example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DispatchQueue`:

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    let result = self.hasValidChanges()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Use result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't return value from another tread because each thread has its own stack. So you have to use callback here.

```
func checkValidValues(completionHandler: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void)) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async { [unowned self] in
        let result = self.hasValidChanges()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        completionHandler(result)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [dispatch group](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup)

```
var b: Bool = false
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "myQueue")

let group = DispatchGroup()
group.enter()

DispatchQueue.global().async {
    b = hasValidValues()
    group.leave()
}

group.notify(queue: queue) {
    //use b
}
```

Comment: here I am returning function to another controller.. My question is how to return and again DispatchQueue.main.async will do same thing. block the UI.

Comment: What do you mean by *will do same thing*?

Comment: Currently it is blocking execution as it is running on main thread.. So If I do same thing on main it will block again..

Comment: You can do it on another queue. I've updated the answer